# Not able to ping and connect to internet from Kali Linux in Virtual Box

Tags: virtualbox, kali-linux

I know and admit that the same question has been asked multiple times in the same forum as well as in others. However, none of those seem to work for me.
I would post a detailed analysis and the steps I have taken up to setup the network adapter in Kali Linux on VirtualBox in Windows 8.1

The uname -r command yields the following:
"4.0.0-kali-amd64" -- gives the version I'm running for Kali Linux.

VirtualBox version I'm running: 4.3.6 r91406

I have installed Kali linux on the virtual box. My network adapter settings are:
1. Bridged on Adapter 1 -- To connect to the internet
2. Host-only on Adapter 2 -- to communicate between my host machine and guest OS

Now, initially, I was not able to ping and ssh into my guest OS from windows. "ifconfig -a" use to show eth0 and lo, but with no inet address on eth0.
So, I changed my settings as shown in the following url:
    https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration
which says to add the following in /etc/network/interfaces file:
    auto eth0
    allow-hotplug eth0
    iface eth0 inet dhcp

What it did was, as shown by "ifconfig -a", it created a new interface, eth1, and assigned it an ip address. However, my eth0 has still not been assigned any ip address, and running the command:
    "ping www.google.com" shows unknown host www.google.com

In addition, following the given url:
     https://superuser.com/questions/678893/cant-access-internet-in-kali-virtualbox
also resulted in no change and I'm still not able to connect to the internet.

Note: It did remove the ssh problem, i.e. allowing me to ssh from windows on the address provided by eth1 -- 192.168.X.X

Comment: The full contents of `/etc/network/interfaces`, and output of the `ip a` and `ip r` commands might be handy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use "bridged adapter," you will need to go to advanced settings and change your promiscuous mode to "allow all".The IP should change to a 10.x.x.x range, instead of 192.168.x.x.

In most instances, NAT would be better for using other non-LAN network functions (SSH, Telnet, etc). On many types of network adapters, you will not be able to use bridged adapter at all.

Answer (score 0):

Change Adapter 1 to NAT to connect to the internet.  The bridged setting is to connect with your network (printers, etc.).